# How to make Sublime Text not autocomplete element names within text elements

Tags: sublimetext3

When I write HTML in Sublime Text 3, I like having autocompletion of attributes and element names and so on, but Sublime Text is always over-predicting things and turning my text content into elements (inappropriately), when the vast majority of the document body I am writing is text, not elements.  What gets really annoying is if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of a line where it believes the word I am typing is a typo of a different element, I get some really frustrating behavior:

[image: completion box popped up]
[image: spurious completion happened]

The workaround I see is to press <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of every line but that isn't particularly ergonomic (and I have severe RSI so I'd rather have things be ergonomic).

Here are the relevant portions of my Preferences.sublime-settings:

```
{
    "auto_complete": false,
    "auto_complete_selector": "source - (comment, string.quoted)",
    "tab_completion": false,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

I have looked at the Sublime Text documentation regarding completions and snippets but it isn't obvious to me how to suppress completions entirely during a text context. I don't currently have any HTML-mode-specific options configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime's HTML autocompletions are implemented in a Python script.

It is possible to edit it, such that HTML tags will only be offered when you type `<` and a letter - instead of offering them while typing "plain" text content inside HTML.

To do this:

1. Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) using Package Control (if it isn't already installed)
2. From the Command Palette, type `PRV: O` and select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
3. Select `HTML`
4. Select `html_completions.py`
5. Find the line `# if the opening < is not here insert that` (https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/77867ed8000601962fec21a012f42b789c42195b/HTML/html_completions.py#L243)
6. Change `completion_list = [(pair[0], '<' + pair[1]) for pair in completion_list]` to `completion_list = []`
7. Save the file

Note that this creates a file that will override the version that comes with ST, so when a new build of ST3 is released, your version will still be used. In case this file is ever updated, it might be a good idea to delete your version to ensure you have the latest changes, and then to re-apply the above steps (if necessary - maybe it will be "fixed" in a future update to not suggest anything when `auto_complete` is set to `false`). To do this:

- `Tools` -> `Browse Packages`
- `HTML`
- Delete `html_completions.py`